# C# - How to determine if source is compiled successfully

Tags: c#

I am running the C# compiler in code, sort of my own IDE.

I create a batch file for the command line.

And run `Process.Start()` and wait till `HasExited` is `true`.

But how do know if the source compiled successfully?

Malcolm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually with command-line apps you can take a look at the return code (ERRORLEVEL in batch files).  0 means success.  Anything else means some sort of failure.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using csc via the process API instead of using the System.CodeDom.Compiler API?  This will give you the same effect (in fact, it calls csc internally), but is cross platform, handles errors, allows you to tweak options programatically more easily, etc.